# Using Munpack to extract attachments of specific file type (Debian/Squeeze)

Tags: email, procmail

I configured `Munpack` on my Debian/Linux to extract attachments from incoming emails.

(For additional context, `Getmail` fetches the emails and pipes it to `Procmail`. A `Procmail` recipe then pipes it to `Munpack`.)

```
| munpack -q -C directory/
```

For some reason, when I get emails with (a) inline attachments (usually `images`) AND (b) document attachments (usually `.csv`), the `.csv` files are completely ruined.

*(Note that this issue doesn't arise when there is only one attachment, which typically is a `.xls` file.*

Is there a way to configure Munpack to:

```
1. Save **ONLY** attachments with the `.csv` extension in the email.

2. Make sure that the **.csv** files are saved as is.
```

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately, U'll probably have to re-write munpack to add the capability of unpacking multiple files.  according to a README that came with v1.5 source, "[t]here must be exactly one message per file.  Munpack cannot deal with multiple messages in a single file, to decode things correctly it must know when one message ends and the next one begins."

i don't know how difficult that re-write would be, as i haven't looked at the source myself; i'm perfectly happy splitting files (use GAWK or PERL or something like that) on the boundaries.

Comment: Given that munpack is from the early 90s and you have it as a reference, rewriting would probably be much easier than writing it in the first place.    I've only just discovered munpack, but two things seems painful - 1 - it renames attachments with spaces.   2. - no way of listing messages and attachments from the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm coming to this party a little late so this response is for future visitors: `munpack-1.6` was released to Unix and Windows in three versions (vanilla, `a`, and `b`).

On Linux systems the respective package manager filename might contain the string `1.6-2`. If so, then these versions also support a `-t` switch which does a better job doing attachment extractions. The big problem here is that this feature is almost never documented **and** not visible when you execute `munpack -?`.

Anyway, on my CentOS-7 systems I always use the command `munpack -tf <filename>`.